# Logging standard for utility library

Tags: java, logging

I am writing a small utility library and I need to do some logging.  I don't want to force the user to have to use a specific logging framework such as Log4J or commons-logging, so should I use SLF4J and include all of the bridges so that it just integrates with whatever they are using? Or should I just use java.util.logging?  I should mention that this is a Maven project as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, for such cases, I have only the following runtime dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And these for testing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So when someone wants to use me, they have to include only the bridge for their logging implementation.

*EDIT*: I use dependency management that's why version is missing :)

Comment: This is what I figured, I just wanted to get the communities take. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is unfortunate that there are so many different logging frameworks out there ...

If you want to avoid tying your clients to a specific logging implementation, then slf4j is the best alternative.  Another alternative is Apache Commons Logging, but it has serious issues; see http://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html.

(If you use java.util.logging you are violating your primary requirement ...)

---

The other alternative is to not do any logging at all in your library.